# Is it possible in c# to take input for input values in Jagged Arrays

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jagged-arrays

```
 int[][] randomNumber = new int[3][];
        randomNumber[0] = new int[2];
        randomNumber[1] = new int[2];
        randomNumber[2] = new int[2];
        Console.WriteLine(randomNumber.Length);

        for(int i= 0; i<randomNumber.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter two people name");
            for(int j =0; j<randomNumber[i].Length; j++)
            {
                randomNumber[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<randomNumber.Length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<randomNumber[i].Length;j++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ",randomNumber[i][j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

*In above problem I want user input for Jagged Array inputs (i.e is there any way possible by which I can decide how many number of array I want to add and also the number of elements inside that array which can be decide by user only?)*

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - you mean you want users to enter two names in one line? No, there's not a built-in way to input an array from a single string. You can have them separate them by commas or some other delimiter and `Split` then into an array. That would be the easier route.

Comment: I don't think you're going to have much luck asking the user for two person names and then parsing their input as int.. Not even Bord designations meet that spec

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Enter two names separated by a space"); randomString[0] = Console.ReadLine().Split()`

Comment: no I mean that is there any way possible by which I can decide how many number of array I want to add and also the number of elements inside that array?

Comment: Oh, sure.. that's doable..

Comment: Then help me please...........

Comment: Do you want to ask for a number of names first and then collect that many names? Or collect names until the user says "stop". You can use a `List<String>`, or dynamically increase the size of the array, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As a starter:

```
int[][] x;

Console.WriteLine("How many times should I ask for numbers?");
int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

x = new int[y][];

for(int i = 0; i<y; i++)){

  Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will you enter this time?");
  int z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

  x[i] = new int[z];

  for(int j = 0; j<z; j++){
    Console.WriteLine("What is the "+j+"+th number?");
    x[i][j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  }
}
```

Or you can skip the second question/loop and just ask:

```
for(int i = 0; i<y; i++)){

  Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers separated by spaces?");
  x[i] = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
}
```

But don't hand that latter one in unless a) you've learnt LINQ or b) you're prepared to investigate how it works and explain it :D

Comment: The change has been implemented. I also correcte dthe same error in a `[z]`